# How to read remote XML via ASP?

Tags: xml, asp-classic

01.00
      
         1250484
      
      
         0

```
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter name="Row1" id="3">
     <Value>19/09/2010 12:19:40|iliani|08000367|63|        0.50|42560175||744213|00|Y</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter name="xICBSXPProxy.AppType" id="4">
     <Value>xEXTServicePrep</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter name="xICBSXPProxy.ProcessingLevel" id="5">

     <Value>1</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter name="TotalRowCount" id="6">
     <Value>1</Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter name="xICBSXPProxy.ProcessingAccept" id="7">
     <Value>Y</Value>

  </Parameter>
  <Parameter name="RowCount" id="8">
     <Value>1</Value>
  </Parameter>
</Message>
</ICBSProxy>
```

this is the response of payment gateway for a transaction .
I need to read via ASP from this remote xml the parameter row1 more exactly the columns that say 744213 wich is transid and the Y that means transaction accepted if there is N then is denied in order to add in my db the status of trans and transid .
Any sample code that could help me ? i searched a full day without success ,
thank you guys

Comment: What is your exact problem? Is it to access the XML data (in that case, you should explain how it is exposed by the remote platform: FTP, webservice, ...)? Is it to parse the XML? Is it to split the row1 data and retrieve the interesting fields? Is it to update your db?

Comment: I need to gather in ASP the two values orderid and trans status and i don't know how to extract that from the following XML that is hosted on the bank server

Comment: once i have this 2 param i could do myself some comparations eg. if transstatus =Y then update my order in db and send client confirmation .. but i don't know how to parse the XML and get this 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to load the xml

```
Set XMLDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0")
XMLDom.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"


objxml.Load "<URL OF XML HERE>"
```

This is to get the `Row1` text

```
xmltext = XMLDom.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//Parameter[@name='Row1']/value").text
```

Here is how to split the text (*if it follows the same principle as the example*)

```
Set r = New RegExp
r.ignorecase = true
r.global = true
r.pattern = "\|\|(.*?)\|.*?\|(.*?)$"

set matches = r.execute( xmltext )(0).submatches

transid = matches.item(0)
yesno = matches.item(1)
```